# How do I nest a JSON array?

Tags: json

I am trying to create a JSON object. It represents a payload of many observations, all sent from a device with a single serial. Each observation has an ID (8 and 17 in the example below), a dimension and a value. I came up with this:

```js
{
 "serial": "10002000",
 "observations": [
  "8": {
   "d": "dimension1",
   "v": "somevalue",
  },
  "17": {
   "d": "dimension2",
   "v": "anothervalue",
  },
 ],
}
```

Which I think demonstrates what I'm after - but it's not syntactically correct JSON. What am I missing?

Comment: Remember: no comma after last item.

Comment: *What am I missing?* What you are missing is the rudimentary understanding of arrays that you could gain from any JS intro or tutorial. Arrays are lists of values called elements, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: Thanks Alex!

Torazaburo - shockingly, I did read a JS intro to get here - I'm just not very good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON array can't have key-value pairs as a single element - both the key and a value are separate elements. When you say `8: {...}`, you're trying to put a whole key-value pair in the array as one element. You could either change `observations` to be an object, with `8` as a property, for example, or you could make each element of the array a new object, where `8` is a property within that object, for example.

Ex:

```
{
    "serial": "10002000",
    "observations": {
        "8": {
            "d": "dimension1",
            "v": "somevalue"
        },
        "17": {
            "d": "dimension2",
            "v": "anothervalue"
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "serial": "10002000",
    "observations": [
        {
            "8": {
                "d": "dimension1",
                "v": "somevalue"
            }
        },
        {
             "17": //and so on
```

Comment: This, and also remember to **not** put commas after last item.

Comment: What is a "JSON array", and is it different from a regular array?

Comment: You've left out the obvious structure of `observations: [{id, d, v}, ...]`.